# How to fix the invalid url query string and path?

Tags: php, url

I always via $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] get query string and path,
But sometimes that will gets a invalid value,

```
#1
?a[]=1&b[]=2
(should be: ?a%5B%5D=1&b%5B%5D=2)

#2
?c%5B%5D=3&d[]=4
(should be: ?c%5B%5D=3&d%5B%5D=4)

#3
/to/path*/a/1
(should be: /to/path%2A/a/1)

#4
/to/path%2A/a*/1
(should be: /to/path%2A/a%2A/1)
```

How do I always get the string has been encoded? if use urlencode() is bad idea, because some of the characters have been encoded or should not be encode.

Comment: You can url decode first then again url encode. This will handle partial encoding.

Comment: Your premise is flawed. URLs should only encode specific tokens that are reserved. So you case of #3: `/to/path*/a/1` **is** correctly encoded. You don't need to (nor don't want to) encode every single possible character. So the entire premise of this question is flawed...

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution, but at the moment it is the only thing I can think of:

```
function parse ($string, $allowed = array('?', '=', '/')) {
    $chars = str_split(urldecode($string));
    $encoded = '';
    foreach ($chars as $char) {
        if (in_array($char, $allowed)) {
            $encoded .= $char;
            continue;
        }
        $encoded .= urlencode($char);
    }

    return $encoded;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/QKFSWmHs

What happens is that first the string is decoded to normalize it (should we worry about double encoding?). After that we simply loop through all characters and check whether the characters should be encoded.

Comment: Is there a  way for high performance ? I think use for-each not good. but thanks.

Comment: Have you tested it and came to the conclusion this is the bottleneck? Or are you just guessing. If you have tested it *and* this is the bottleneck: how many URL are you going to parse per request?

Comment: @joe urlencode/urldecode goes internally char by char - in a loop. Here we're doing the loop ourselves and internally it doesn't need to loop over the string now. This is surely _not_ a bottleneck.

Comment: @joe Stop guessing and start profiling. How many paths / querystrings do you think there are above 1000 characters.